# Magento 2 InstallSchema : Is my assumption correct?

Tags: product, php-5.4, magento2-dev-beta, setup-script

I'm creating table with reference key of `catalog_product_entity`, here I'm little bit of confusing while converting **Magento 1.0** to **Magento 2.0**.

Can you clarify it.

In magento 1.0 simply I can run the below script it will execute and create the table right?

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `{$this->getTable('custom_info')}`;
CREATE TABLE `{$this->getTable('custom_info')}` (
  `id` INTEGER unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `product_id` INTEGER unsigned NOT NULL,
  `email` TEXT NOT NULL default '',
  `is_active` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date` DATETIME default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',  
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `FK_custom_PRODUCT_ID` (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_custom_PRODUCT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `{$this->getTable('catalog_product_entity')}` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

");

$installer->endSetup();
```

In Magento 2.0 I have written code as below is it correct procedure or else wrong?

```
<?php

namespace Learning\Custom\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

    /**
 * Installs DB schema for a module
 *
 * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
 * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
 * @return void
 */
public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;
    $installer->startSetup();

    $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable($installer->getTable('outofstocksubscription_info'))
        ->addColumn(
            'id',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            10,
            ['identity' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Post ID'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'product_id',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            10,
            ['unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
            'Product Id'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'email',
            Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false,],
            'E Mail'
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'is_active',
            Table::TYPE_BOOLEAN,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
            'Is Active'
        )
        ->addForeignKey(
            $installer->getFkName('outofstocksubscription_info', 'product_id', 'catalog_product_entity', 'entity_id'),
            'product_id',
            $installer->getTable('catalog_product_entity'),
            'entity_id',
            Table::ACTION_CASCADE
        )
        ->addColumn(
            'date',
            Table::TYPE_DATE,
            null,
            [],
            'Date'
        )
        ->setComment(
            'Out of Stock Subscription'
        );

    $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
    $installer->endSetup();
}

}
```

If it is wrong please correct me.

When I ran command: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` error is came.

**Error**

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key
>   constraint, query was: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   `custom_info` (
>       `id` smallint NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Post ID' ,
>       `product_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Product Id' ,
>       `email` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'E Mail' ,
>       `is_active` bool NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Is Active' ,
>       `date` date NULL COMMENT 'Date' ,
>       PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>       CONSTRAINT `CUSTOM__INFO_ID_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`)
>   ON DELETE CASCADE   ) COMMENT='Custom Table'
>   ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need remove params 6 in addForeignKey function because in:

```
/**
 * Add Foreign Key to table
 *
 * @param string $fkName        the foreign key name
 * @param string $column        the foreign key column name
 * @param string $refTable      the reference table name
 * @param string $refColumn     the reference table column name
 * @param string $onDelete      the action on delete row
 * @return $this
 * @throws \Zend_Db_Exception
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 */
public function addForeignKey($fkName, $column, $refTable, $refColumn, $onDelete = null)
{
    $upperName = strtoupper($fkName);

    // validate column name
    if (!isset($this->_columns[strtoupper($column)])) {
        throw new \Zend_Db_Exception('Undefined column "' . $column . '"');
    }

    switch ($onDelete) {
        case self::ACTION_CASCADE:
        case self::ACTION_RESTRICT:
        case self::ACTION_SET_DEFAULT:
        case self::ACTION_SET_NULL:
            break;
        default:
            $onDelete = self::ACTION_NO_ACTION;
    }

    $this->_foreignKeys[$upperName] = [
        'FK_NAME' => $fkName,
        'COLUMN_NAME' => $column,
        'REF_TABLE_NAME' => $refTable,
        'REF_COLUMN_NAME' => $refColumn,
        'ON_DELETE' => $onDelete
    ];

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: When I ran my script Error is trowing. see my thread I have updated.

Comment: type of `entity_id` in `catalog_product_entity` as `int(10)` but `id` column in `custom_info`  have type `smallint(6)`. You should change and try again

Comment: I have modified as you instructed, now no error is came. but when I ran website the script is not executed (table not created).

Comment: you access `setup_module` table, find and delete record have `module` column as `Learning_Custom`  (name of your module) , after run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: I think `setup_module` (Magento 2.0) is equal to `core_resource` (Magento 1.0) right?

Comment: Yeah, you are right ! It working ?

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks ok. The main difference with upgrade or install script in magento2 is, that you dont have several scripts. Magento2 just have one script, running multiple times, so you have to handle your versioning by yourself.

Comment: When I ran my script Error is trowing. see my thread I have updated.